# GIT: connect unreleated branches without full history

Tags: git

We have a git repository in our company with a project.

Our customer has also a git repository and we have to push to the customer repository the productive code.

Currently the two git repositories do not have a common history.

I tried now to connect the two repository and added the customer as a remote to my local repository.

My goal is that after releasing a version, I can easily push the current code to the customer repository. Thereby only one commit with all the changes to the last version should be visible by the customers repository.

To connect our code branches with the customer branches I tried to pull the customer branch into our branch an vice-versa. But in the end, git always wants to commit our full history to the customer. How can I connect the branches without sharing our complete commit history? The two branches have currently the same content.

As soon the connection is done, I could use rebase or squash to combine several branches. But when I try to do this with the first commit than this ends in a endless resolving conflicts for all the vast commits already done.

More explanation to the commit history.
The goal should be something like this:

Our Repository:

- Branch for Develop: C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> C5 -> C6 -> C7
- Branch for Customer: C3* -> C5*
- C3*: contains C1 to C3
- C5*: contains C4 and C5

Customer Repository:

- C3* -> C5*

At the moment the customer repository and our repository have no connection/history in common. Now I would like to connect them.

Comment: Do the two code bases have anything in common?

Comment: you need to explain more to get a more precise answer.

Comment: Yes the code is the same.
The commit history should not be the same.

Comment: If the code is the same but will have a different history between your work and your customer's work, maybe you can find a common starting point between both your codebases, then treat that as the shared repository that you both work from? That's a pretty normal use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to sync your repo with an unrelated repo. The whole point of git is of a *Version Control System*, which means recording every commit. The only way to get rid of your history (that I know of) is to delete your `.git` file and start a new repo. Then they will only see your initial commit.

I should add that everyone makes mistakes and I wouldn't be shy in admiting this. if there was at one point a file in your git history which contains sensitive material you can try the [BFG repo cleaner](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/), it works wonders.

Comment: It seems git is not intended to do what I wanted.
Some solution would be to keep the histories unrelated and use on the customer branch:

git merge develop --squash --allow-unrelated-histories